# Python loop through other python files and csva

Tags: python, loops, csv

I have multiple `.csv` files that I want to pass through a python script (`script.py`) one at a time, using another python script (chunk_script.py).

```
import os
import csv
import sys
import time

for i in range(1,10):
    filename = 'File_{}.csv'.format(i)
    os.system("python script.py filename")
    time.sleep(1000)
```

The goal is to have all 10 of these `.csv` files go through the `script.py` using the `chunk_script.py` on the command line. The above keeps returning an error that it cannot find the file. It seems that it is not pulling in the `filename` declared.

Comment: ... and your question is?

Comment: And which error does it return?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this

```
for i in range(1,10):
    filename = 'File_{}.csv'.format(i)
    os.system("python script.py {}".format(filename))
    time.sleep(1000)
```

You are calling your script.py on file which name is 'filename' instead 
'File_xxxx.cvs'